# Page builder by Siteorigin showing problem in wp 5

Tags: wordpress

I made my site with a theme which recommended **page builder by siteorigin** for batter experience. recently i updated **wordpress** to latest version and also i updated page builder.Now i made a page with this page builder before the **wordpress 5.0** and now i tried a lot to edit the page with page builder but it is not showing when i click on edit button it's redirecting me to class Editor.

***Note: i used classic editor and Disable Gutenberg plugin also to fix this but i failed***

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, you've made progress since posting. If not, try temporarily deactivating all plugins except for the Classic Editor plugin and those plugins authored by SiteOrigin. In this state, does the issue resolve?